# Way to prevent Windows from shutting down in WinUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, winui

I'm looking if there is a way to prevent a user from shutting down windows until a certain action is completed in WinUI. Is this possible?

I've seen it done using Windows Forms but I don't know if there's an equivalent method for WinUI.

Comment: I think  `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded` is not specific for WinForms, you should better describe the problem and show samples of code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: WinUI3 applications can utilize [Shutdown Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/shutting-down#shutdown-notifications) to cancel shutting down. For an example which utilizes messages, see [WinUI3_Transparent](https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_Transparent/blob/86f5fff5cde4784422c6551b030c2b147e4b11f3/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L209). @aklevans any update?